# Why this program is giving nan is the distance between the points?

Tags: c++, oop, friend

Why this program is giving nan is the distance between the points?
I have made it to use friend function and oop concept but whenever i try to find the distance between coords it shows either zero of nan

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class point{
    int x,y;
    friend void disCoord(point,point);
    public:
    point(int a,int b){
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    void displaypoint(){
        cout<<"the point is("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<endl;
    }

};//END OF CLASS
void disCoord(point o1,point o2){
    double dis=sqrt(pow(o2.x-o1.x,2)-pow(o2.y-o1.y,2));
    cout<<"The distance between point"<<"("<<o1.x<<","<<o1.y<<") and point"<<"("<<o2.x<<"," 
<<o2.y<<") is "<<dis<<endl;
}


int main(){
    point A=point(1,2);
    point B=point(1,3);
    A.displaypoint();
    B.displaypoint();
    disCoord(A,B);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The used formula is wrong.

Comment: `point A=point(1,2); point B=point(1,3);` Change that to -->  `point A(1,2); point B(1,3);`.  There is no need to create unnecessary temporary objects,

Comment: Pythagorean theorem: `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`. You're trying to find `c`, the hypotenuse of a triangle whose legs are the difference in X and Y between two points. So, `c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you are using incorrect formula which result in taking square root of negative number. In particular, in your case

`dis` = sqrt((1-1)<sup>2</sup> - (3-2)<sup>2</sup>)

= sqrt(0 - 1) = sqrt(-1)

And i quote from [nan documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nan-function/)

> The NaN values are used to identify undefined or non-representable values for floating-point elements, **such as the square root of negative numbers** or the result of 0/0.

To **solve** this, replace `double dis=sqrt(pow(o2.x-o1.x,2)-pow(o2.y-o1.y,2));` with:

```
double dis=sqrt(pow(o2.x-o1.x,2) + pow(o2.y-o1.y,2));
```

Note there is a `+` in between while you were using `-` for some reason.

This is because the **actual(correct) formula** for calculating distance is:

d(P,Q) = sqrt((x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Better yet, use `hypot()`.

Comment: Actually `hypot` is slower, but it handles very-large numbers correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, the formula you're using is incorrect. BUT, the reason you're getting a `NaN` or `0` as a result is slightly more complicated.

Your test points `(1,2)` and `(1,3)` share the same `X` component. So, your formula:

```
double dis=sqrt(pow(o2.x-o1.x,2)-pow(o2.y-o1.y,2));
```

Resolves to:

```
dis = sqrt(pow(1-1,2) - pow(3-2,2))
```

or

```
dis = sqrt(0 - 1)
```

Which we all affectionately know as `i`, the square root of `-1`. That's one of the few cases that will (correctly) yield a result of `NaN`. (NAN means "Not A Number," in case that wasn't clear.)

The correct distance formula:

```
sqrt(pow(o2.x-o1.x,2) + pow(o2.y-o1.y,2))
```

Doesn't allow for a negative argument to `sqrt`, so this never happens.

It's tough to find these issues if you're not sure what you're looking for. It'd be easier to debug if you didn't do everything on one line:

```
double a2 = pow(o2.x-o1.x,2);
double b2 = pow(o2.y-o1.y,2);
double c2 = a2 + b2;
double c = sqrt(c2);
```

That's overly verbose, but the general idea is to split complex statements up into components. It's easier to read, easier to debug, and, if you'd done this, you'd have seen that `c2` was negative.

White space is cheap, carriage returns cost nothing. Don't scrimp on keystrokes in order to save time.